Is it possible to specify input files in bazel with $ in the filename?
I would like to specify input files to bazel with names like ContextFinder$5.class.
Consider the following bazel BUILD file:
package(<redacted>)

filegroup(
    name = "class_overrides",
    srcs = [
      "ContextFinder$$1.class",
      "ContextFinder$$2.class",
      "ContextFinder$$3.class",
      "ContextFinder$$4.class",
      "ContextFinder$$5.class",
      "ContextFinder.class"
    ],
)

When I try to build a target that includes this, I get errors saying missing input file...ContextFinder$$1.class.
If I do not double-up the $, I instead get the following error:
in cmd attribute of genrule rule <redacted>
'$1' syntax is not supported; use '$(1)' instead for "Make" variables, or escape the '$' as '$$' if you intended this for the shell

Is it possible at all to specify input filenames with $ in them?

The problem here is that filegroup doesn't do make variable substitution, while cmd of genrule does.
I assume you have a genrule that uses $(SRCS) like this:
genrule(
  name = "gen",
  srcs = [":class_overrides"],
  outs = ["out"],
  cmd = "echo $(SRCS) > $@",
)

filegroup(
    name = "class_overrides",
    srcs = [
      "ContextFinder$1.class",
      ...
    ],
)

The srcs of the filegroup needs the real file name (ContextFinder$1.class), and then the $(SRCS) in cmd of the genrule gets substituted (echo $(SRCS) > $@ -> echo ContextFinder$1.class > output.txt), and make variable substitution finds the $1, and there's no chance to escape that.
One workaround is to avoid specifying the names containing $, e.g. something like cmd = "echo *.class > $@", since the *.class will be expanded by the shell at execution time rather than during bazel analysis of the genrule.
Another option is to not use a genrule and write a small Starlark rule that does what you need. A simple example would be:
defs.bzl:
def _generate_overrides_impl(ctx):
  out = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name + ".out")
  files = depset(transitive = [l.files for l in ctx.attr.srcs])
  ctx.actions.write(
      output = out,
      content = "\n".join([f.path for f in files.to_list()]),
  )
  return DefaultInfo(files = depset([out]))

generate_overrides = rule(
  implementation = _generate_overrides_impl,
  attrs = {
    "srcs": attr.label_list(),
  },
)

BUILD.bazel:
load(":defs.bzl", "generate_overrides")

generate_overrides(
  name = "generate_overrides",
  srcs = [":class_overrides"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "class_overrides",
    srcs = [
      "ContextFinder$1.class",
      ...
    ],
)

$ bazel build generate_overrides
INFO: Analyzed target //:generate_overrides (1 packages loaded, 7 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:generate_overrides up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/generate_overrides.out
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.084s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
$ cat bazel-bin/generate_overrides.out
ContextFinder$1.class
ContextFinder$2.class
ContextFinder$3.class
ContextFinder$4.class
ContextFinder$5.class

But this depends on what you need to do.

Another option:
One way to find the common directory in a function/macro from a list of files obtained using glob():
defs.bzl:
def get_common_dirname(files):
  directories = {}  # Starlark does not have set(), so use a dict
  for f in files:
    directory, filename = f.rsplit("/", 1)
    directories[directory] = True
  if len(directories) > 1:
    fail("not all in a common directory")
  return directories.keys()[0]

BUILD.bazel:
load(":defs.bzl", "get_common_dirname")

files = glob(["**/*.class"])

genrule(
  name = "gen2",
  srcs = [":class_overrides"],
  outs = ["out2"],
  cmd = """echo "%s" > $@""" % get_common_dirname(files),
)

# this is not strictly necessary for this example, because
# files could go directly into the srcs of the genrule above
filegroup(
    name = "class_overrides",
    srcs = files,
)


For the first workaround, how might I pass the path to the directory containing those files to the genrule as an input?

Inside the genrule you could find the classes and determine the directory. At that point it's a little shell programming puzzle: cmd = """directory="$$(dirname $$(find . -name '*.class' -print -quit))" && echo "$$directory" > $@""",. Not super portable, but an idea. Sticking to BUILD files and macros is a little trickier because you can't really inspect the contents of a filegroup in a BUILD file/macro -- that has to be done in a starlark rule. You can use glob() and pass the resulting list of files to a function that finds the common directory, but you have to construct things just right

I edited the answer to add an example for using just build files / macros
